# Twilio: Buzzing in the Front Door

Tags: twilio

I'd like to switch to Twilio, I have a very simple use case: the front door for my building.

**Today:** When someone buzzes our number, the front door calls my DID from one of two phone lines and my phone and my partner's phone ring (showing the front door callerid) at the same time. One of us answers and buzzes the person in.

With Twilio I would enqueue the incoming call, and place two calls simultaneously. I would then do "Human Detection" (*press 1*), join the incoming call to the human and drop the other ringing call.

This all seems reasonable, except how do I get the caller id to our phones so we know it's someone buzzing in? Can I register our phones to allow "any" callerid from Twilio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you can achieve this with a simpler approach than queuing and placing new calls.

When you receive the incoming call to your Twilio number you can return a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) with multiple [`<Number>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number). This will place the calls onto the phone numbers, using the original incoming caller ID, so it will appear to be coming from the original number.

Normally using `<Number>` would cause the other calls to be canceled once the first one is answered. But, you can add a [`url` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) to the `<Number>` to play TwiML to the person answering, before connecting to the incoming call. This is known as a [whisper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) and allows you to perform the human detection using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather). Then, once the whisper is over and the call connects, the other calls are dropped. So, your first TwiML should look a bit like this:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial answerOnBridge="true">
    <Number url="/detect">+123456789</Number>
    <Number url="/detect">+198765432</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then `/detect` should look like this:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="/gather-input" numDigits="1">
    <Say>You are getting a call from your front door, press 1 to accept</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Then the `/gather-input` should respond with a `<Hangup>` if 1 was not pressed, and an empty `<Response>` if you want to connect. For example (in Ruby-like pseudocode):

```
post '/gather-input' do
  if params["Digits"] == 1
    return "<Response/>"
  else 
    return "<Response><Hangup/></Response>"
  end
end
```